# list of strings differ by suffix

Tags: python

Hi I want to create a list which contains strings differ only by suffix ie. like this

```
['./name[@val="1"]/Output1', './name[@val="1"]/Output2','./name[@val="1"]/Output3']
```

I tried to iterate through a for loop and appending the suffix int value like this

```
dummy = []
for I in range(1,5):
    dummy.append('./Timestamp[@absCycle='"'+i'"']/Output'+i)
```

Then I realized I can't append int value `i` to a string, is there any other way to do this?

**edit:** Also how to do that inside a string? I mean how if I want a list like

```
 ['./name[@val="1"]/Output', './name[@val="2"]/Output','./name[@val="3"]/Output']
```

Thank you

Comment: thanks @falsetru. And how to do that inside a string? ex: for `@val1` in the above string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code change `i` to `str(i)` which typecasts the integer to a string.

You should also try to use single line list comprehension, which is cleaner and more pythonic.

```
dummy = [ ('./name[@val="1"]/Output' + str(i) ) for i in xrange(0,5)]
```

And also use formatting instead of concatenations.

```
[ './name[@val="1"]/Output{0}'.format(i)  for i in xrange(0,5)]
```

Comment: Thanks @ DhruvPathak. And how can i do that inside a string? I mean if i want a list like 
`['./name[@val="1"]/Output', './name[@val="2"]/Output','./name[@val="3"]/Output']`

Comment: @user20044033 again use formatting like `['./name[@val="{0}"]/Output'.format(i)`  
See : http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Answer (score 1):

Use `str()`

```
dummy = []
for i in range(1,5):
    dummy.append('./Timestamp[@absCycle='"'+i'"']/Output'+str(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dummy = []
for i in range(1,5):
    dummy.append('./Timestamp[@absCycle="'+ str(i) +'"]/Output'+str(i))
```